# Is there a name for UI elements that update/change itself in the background?

Tags: ui-element

For instance, Windows Live Tiles or Android's App Actions in the app drawer. For clarity, this is what [FOSS Mint](https://www.fossmint.com/android-9-0-pie-features/) says about App Actions:

> For example, your phone will suggest your most recent playlist when you connect earphones to it. Or suggest that you call your mom to check on her during the week.

(It updates or changes itself in the background, and the user doesn't change it consciously.)

Is there a technical term for those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't they "**Push**" elements, as opposed to "Pull" ones?

http://ui-patterns.com/blog/Designing-for-push-and-pull-in-web-design states

> "When we design to influence our users through a **push** strategy, we begin by forecasting their needs and then designing the most efficient system to ensure everything our users need is available at the right time and the right place."

The link then gives examples, much like the ones you indicate.

> "**push** tends to be a replication of past experience tweaking the current environment by minor changes"

So it appears that the "most recent playlist" then echoes their previous listening pattern, and "call your mom" is based on a previously established calling pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a widely-used generic term, but in an accessibility context such UI elements would often be considered ["live regions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).